# Adding onClick Listener on dynamically created elements not working

Tags: java, android

I am creating dynamic `textview` on runtime. on adding `onClick()` Listener. it works only on the last `textview` created on runtime and not on every `textview` created.
This is my code:-

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Object> task) {
    if (task.isComplete()) {
        ArrayList<Document> tagLocat = (ArrayList<Document>) task.getResult();
        tv=new TextView[tagLocat.size()];

            for (i = 0; i < tagLocat.size(); i++) {
            Document doc = tagLocat.get(i);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            Log.i("Document", "" + doc);
             notification = doc.getString("notification");
            Log.i("Double", "" + notification);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lparams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
            tv1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv1.setTag(i);
            tv1.setId(i);
            tv1.setTextSize(30);
            tv1.setPadding(50, 0 ,0,0);

            tv1.setText(notification);
            tv[i] = tv1;
            linearLayout.addView(tv[i]);

           tv[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            tv[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("Exception",task.getException().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are changing reference of view that's why onClick not working. below both answers are correct check them once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your textview in array after set onclicklistener

like

```
                    tv1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                    tv1.setTag(i);
                    tv1.setId(i);
                    tv1.setTextSize(30);
                    tv1.setPadding(50, 0 ,0,0);

                    tv1.setText(notification);                    

                   tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                    tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                        }
                    });

                    tv[i] = tv1;
                    linearLayout.addView(tv[i]);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me...thanks for your help!!@Raja

Answer (score 0):

Set `onClickListener` before adding view .

Solution:-

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tagLocat.size(); i++) {
        // Do stuff here
        tv[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        tv[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        });
        tv[i] = tv1;
        linearLayout.addView(tv[i]);

    }
```

Make sure this will not toggle the color `onClick()`.If you want such behaviour you need to maintain the state of `TextView`.

Comment: the code works even with the global variable..thanks for your help!!@ADM